# using zypper for patching

Tags: linux, glibc, suse, zypper

Based on the article https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7016113 I am trying to apply the glibc patches. However, I cannot update the system online as it is not connected to internet. I have downloaded the relevant security patches

```
glibc-html-2.11.3-17.45.55.5 
glibc-i18ndata-2.11.3-17.45.55.5    
glibc-info-2.11.3-17.45.55.5 
glibc-locale-2.11.3-17.45.55.5    
glibc-profile-2.11.3-17.45.55.5 
nscd-2.11.3-17.45.55.5
```

All these are .rpm files. However,I am not sure how to apply these to the system. What is the command that I need to use? As per SUSE documentation it refers to using zypper ,but not sure on the exact procedure. Please let me know how do I apply these and how do I check if there are any dependencies that I need to install before this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can just do:

```
zypper in <path-to-rpm> <path-to-other-rpm>
```

if there are any missing dependencies, zypper will tell you.

You can also do it the **old** way using `rpm`:

```
rpm -Uvh <path-to-rpm> <path-to-other-rpm>
```

which basically does the same...